# How do I connect Microsoft team's channel with work item in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, office365, microsoft-teams

We have microsoft azure devops for our Software development activity.

We would like to have some kind of chatting thing to be integrated with work item(Bug,Task,user-story) on azure devops.

I find Microsoft team's channel as extremely useful but I couldn't find any easy way to integrate it with azure devops work item other than copy pasting the channel link.

I couldn't find any plug in also .

Any help is appreciated

Comment: This question isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow, and will probably get closed. for Azure DevOps extensions for Teams, check out this: https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/teams/

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT I have not done much on this now. I will try this over the week-end and let you know

Comment: @Shiva, Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I connect Microsoft team's channel with work item in azure devops

Andrew provided a great guide document:

[Microsoft Teams with Azure DevOps Services](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/teams/)

You could integrate Micosoft teams with Azure devops. Then we could configure the connectors to subscribe about workitems (Commented,Create,deleted,... ):

[image]

Then we will receive the notifications about the workitems in the Micosoft teams:

[image]

Hope this helps.